# Other words for 'playgirl'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a more elegant term to replace 'playgirl'.

Playgirl (n); a woman who pursues a life of pleasure without responsibility or attachments, especially one who is of comfortable means.

The word should be suitable to replace 'playboy' in, for example;

> "Genius, billionaire, **playboy**, philanthropist” line in by Ironman.

Comment: Is there a social or age class distinction to the subject?  "Socialite" might fit under some circumstances, but then so might "mall rat."

Comment: The answers below at this time are provided at the duplicate, but surely 'playboy' must also involve a raffish element. This isn't made absolutely clear in OP's definition of 'playgirl'.

Answer (score 3):

A ***socialite*** is defined at [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/socialite) as

> someone who spends a lot of time in fashionable social circles. A socialite gets invited to all the best parties and says yes to all of them.

Although the word's connotation may be neutral when it simply refers to a woman, often possessed of independent wealth, who is prominent in society, it may be somewhat more pointed.

Consider the portrait of a ***socialite*** in Ellen Kay's poem, "Pathedy of Manners":

```
...afraid to wonder what she might have known,
With all that wealth and mind had offered her,
She shuns conviction, choosing to infer
Tenets of every mind except her own.

A hundred people call, though not one friend,
To parry a hundred doubts with nimble talk.
Her meanings lost in manners, she will walk
Alone in brilliant circles to the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion i'd make is "a lady of leisure".